# Skype4Py replying

Tags: python, python-2.7, skype, skype4py

I am using skype4py now and I am looking how to send a message if someone sends me a message.

The website of of Skype4Py is not very helpfull on this subject

I can already send a message but only when I call a script and not if a message comes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get chat from `ChatMessage`.Chat and call its method [sendMessaage](http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/Skype4Py.chat.Chat-class.html#SendMessage).
Following simple callback will do the trick:

```
def OnMessageStatus(msg, status):
    if status == Skype4Py.cmsReceived:
        msg.Chat.SendMessage("n/a")
```